# upload updated details in excel to mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, excel, batch-file

I have a batch file which updates the excel file by adding the latest values to it. The details are already there in the MySQL as a table. Once the details are updated. For eg after the end of day update a 10 new rows are added to the excel file. I need to add those 10 rows to the table defined in the database. Is it possible? I am able to overwrite the whole table again. Since it takes a lot of time and gives performance issues, I would like to append only the latest rows. If it is possible can it be done programatically so that we can put it as a batch which updates the database after the excel files are updated.

Consider daily update of the table with the price values of stocks. The update can also be done once in a week. Just has to update the table with the latest values only since the table may contain millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done programmatically or batch job using pl/SQL. 
Here is the logic. Find the max() of the table row pk id. Compare the id value from excel and update the table with those excel rows that are above the max id.